# Missing Namespace with Office

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-on-prem, word-automation

I am trying to develop a custom solution that makes use of the Word Automation Service but I keep running into a snag.

The reference article I am following says that I need to make use of the `Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions` namespace however I am getting the following build error:

> `The type or namespace name 'Word' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

These are the assembly references that I have in my project:

[image: VS Assembly References]

I am sure I am missing something fairly basic but I am not sure what. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `Microsoft.Office.Word.Server` which is located in the GAC (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`). It is not safe to reference `Microsoft.Office.Interop.*` assemblies in a server application.

Comment: That has worked! Why doesn't that assembly appear in the normal list when adding references? Also why is it unsafe to reference `Microsoft.Office.Interop`?

Comment: The assembly list is pulled from `C:\Windows\assembly`, but in .NET 4.0, the GAC was moved to the path I previously provided. As for the Interop assemblies, [`KB257757`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) does a good job of explaining it. The Interop assemblies are used to control an Office client, and that KB goes into why using Office client for automation isn't supported for server-side code.